# Can not edit build.prop

Tags: editing

I am trying to edit the lcd density in build.prop in /system but every time after reboot my changes are lost..

I tried to adb pull + edit + adb push in normal and recovery mode.. 
also i tried fileexpert and super manager but nothing worked.

I heard many people saying about root explorer but its not free.. I want to be sure if my problem will be solved with root explorer then i will buy it..

Please help me out guys..

I am using android 2.3.3 on HTC HD2. My Rom is custom one (HyperDroidGBX-v12)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question as found the solution.
We can edit build.prop from mobile. I downloaded ES file explorer which is free. then from optin set "root explorer" and set "mount system as read/write" 
Now edit build.prop and save it using ES file explorer's editor then uncheck "root explorer" and "mount system as read/write" for safety..

hope it wil help someone :)

Comment: Yes, newer versions of ES File Explorer do not allow write to dangerous directories if "Root Explorer" is not enabled in the left menu. The full path to the "Root Explorer" option is Tap in the top left corner, in the menu icon, the left menu appears, then scroll down to Tools, and finally enable Root Explorer. Now, if device is rooted, ES File Explorer will allow to overwrite system files.

Answer (score 0):

Root Explorer won't solve your problem any more than adb, although it's a great app.

First, I'd try making sure you remount `/system` as read-only after you push the modified file.  If that doesn't work I would assume your bootloader is checking the file and replacing it when it doesn't match what it should be.  To help you further, I think we need to know what phone you have; please add that to the question.  Your version of Android, name of your ROM if it's custom, etc. will also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use TWRP

Reboot to recovery (TWRP)

Click Mount

Deselect mount system partition as read-only

Done